# Is this an implication or would it be better to make it an equivalence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just started learning about logic symbols in math and I'm having a hard time with implications and equivalences. Specifically with knowing when to use which. I know what they mean and I can understand them when reading them, but when it comes to writing them myself, I fall into a loop where both seem to work. I just can't seem to trust myself to make the right judgement.

For example let $\tan(v) = 7$ and let $b$ be the adjacent side for angle $v$ and $a$ the opposite side, in a right triangle. So, $$\big(\tan(v) = \frac{a}{b} \land \tan(v)=7 \big)\implies b=1.$$

But isn't it also true going right to left, therefore making it equivalent?

Comment: No, $a$ may be $14$ and $b=2$. You are claiming that a fraction that equals $2$ must have the denominator $1$.

Comment: Could you please be more clear? I can't tell if you mean that it's an invalid equivalence and/or implication. I know that we can't know what $b$ actually is, but we can just imagine a proportional triangle where the fractions are equal. Therefore I'm trying to say that if $tan(v) = 7$, then we can assume $b = 1$.

Comment: In fact you claim $a/b=7\Rightarrow b=1$ which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P\iff Q$$ is an equivalence. It contains these two implications: $$P\implies Q,\\P\impliedby Q \quad(\text{meaning } \;Q\implies P).$$

The statement $P\implies Q$ just means that $P$ being the case **forces** $Q$ to be the case.

The statement $P\iff Q$ just means that $P$ being the case **forces** $Q$ to be the case, and vice-versa.

---

Correction of your given statement, and additional observations: $$\big(\tan(v) = \frac{a}{b} \land \tan(v)=7 \big)\implies \frac{a}{b}=7;\\\frac{a}{b}=7\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies b=1;\\\big(\tan(v) = \frac{a}{b} \land \tan(v)=7 \big)\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies b=1;\\\frac{a}{b}=7\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies \big(\tan(v) = \frac{a}{b} \land \tan(v)=7 \big).$$